# Can we design a generic function where both integer and string addition to be done?

Tags: java

```
class generic<T> {
    T a;
    T b;

    generic(T a, T b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public T sum() {
        return (a+b);
    }
}
```

//can er design this as it takes a input both as integer and string and //give the append result as the same return type.

Comment: Well yes... through another (generic) [`BiFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html), but that is most probably  not  what you had in mind. Since primitives are not allowed as generic types and `String` is a special case, this is not (easily) possible.

Comment: note about your code: you have to specify return type here `public sum()`

Comment: The core question is: why do you want this? What is wrong with writing two methods `int sum(int lhs, int rhs)` and `String concat(String lhs, String rhs)`?  This has the added benefit that the semantics are clearly promoted though the methods's names. Overall,  this very much seems  like an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: after reading the question one more time, I understood that it controversial because of that `give the append result as the same return type`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `instanceof` operator.

You can check for the type of T by asking if instance variable a or b is an instance of String or Integer and make a decision accordingly.

```
class Generic<T>
{
    T a;
    T b;

    Generic(T a,T b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public T sum() {
        if (a instanceof String && b instanceof String) {
           // string concatenation e.g. return a + b + "\n";
        } else if (a instanceof Integer && b instanceof Integer) {
           // integer addition e.g. return a + b;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Note that you'd have to use class types and not primitive types while creating an object of Generic

More notably, you may be able to design the components of your implementation in a better way than to use this Generic class. (Perhaps, inheritance?)

Comment: Do not use `instanceof`, it is not scalable.

Comment: @Turing85 Agreed. `instanceof` may not be the best approach and the OP can probably look deeper at their design to avoid this kind of problem completely.

Comment: Wouldn't the compiler complain about `sum` not being initialized?

Comment: Sum would have to be initialized. I was just giving a sample and have removed sum altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Not like that but you could do something like this:

```
public class Adding{

 public static void main(String []args){
    String string = "12";
    Integer integer = 20;
    System.out.println(add(string, integer));
 }

 private static int add (Object a, Object b) {
     return toInt(a) + toInt(b);
 }

 private static int toInt (Object obj) {
     if (obj.getClass() == String.class) {
         return Integer.parseInt((String)obj);
     } else if (obj.getClass() == Integer.class) {
         return (Integer) obj;
     } else {
        //throw an exception
        return 0;
     }
 }
```

Edit: you could also use your generic types here too

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write one. Just use the existing one like so.

```
BiFunction<String, String, String> biStr = (s1, s2) -> s1 + s2;
BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> biInt = (n1, n2) -> n1 + n2;

System.out.println(biStr.apply("One", "two"));
System.out.println(biInt.apply(10, 6));
```